# OSX Safari/quicktime not sending cookie with request for media file

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, html5-audio

I've written a web application that serves media files over http for playback in a html5 audio element. Before serving a media file, the server checks that a cookie is supplied with a current PHP session id like this:

PHPSESSID=3u90bfmqepd14s4rvslmrv69d1

It seems that IE/Firefox/Chrome all send the cookie along with the request for the audio file, however in OSX Safari the request is sent with a different user agent string (containing 'quicktime') and no cookie. Presumably this is because quicktime takes care of the audio playback capabilities of the browser, unfortunately cookies set in the browser aren't carried over.

Am I going to have to issue clients with a temporary access code that can be passed on the query string along with the request for a media file? Or is there any easier way around this issue?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by implementing an alternative authentication flow. Each request for a media file now sends an authentication token on the query string. This token is generated per user on login and is valid for the duration of the session.

If the cookie is set or a valid auth key is passed on the query string then the media file is served.

For additional security consider storing the token against the client IP server side and validating that the request comes from the same IP the token was generated for before serving the media file to the client

Comment: This does not really solve the problem. Without being able to match the session we cannot verify a logged user, the tokenized links are completely portable and non secure. My links have tokens, plus I need to make the links non portable by limiting delivery to logged users thus properly securing the content. I believe this issue breaks secure file delivery for Safari, is a bug, and needs a fix asap. Perhaps QuickTime has some unique auth procedure which I dont know about, but even if that is so who can scope the work required make a special case for QT in every private video client?

Comment: You can mitigate against someone sharing the token by generating it just in time and expiring it after a very short time instead of keeping it valid for the duration of the session.

Comment: I wouldnt limit time to anything but session, download speeds vary. Your above token per session solution is great and the best thing we have for now. I wasnt dis'n your solution, I was rather trying to point out the fact for Safari that we cant properly work with the current Safari video playback and something needs to be done.
Your session tokens fix is the best workaround, but still allows anyone with the link to access the videos while the link owner is logged in. Maybe OK for the local swingers clubs video sharing server but Im sure it wouldnt wash at the CIA ;) Was does youtube do?

Comment: Any progress on this?  I am having the same issue.  I need to lock down our .mp3 files as they  contain very private information.  I was relying on ASP.NET Identity to perform authentication.  But, without a cookie in the Request header, I'm screwed... (pardon my French)

Comment: This is the best we have at the minute - for additional security consider storing the token against the client IP server side and validating that the request comes from the same IP the token was generated for